# SVG into font changes shape

Tags: svg, fonts, icons, adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator to create an SVG icon I can later use to create a .ttf font however icon I've created looks totally different when loading into tools like Glyphter or IcoMoon.

Here's my image

[image]

Here's how it looks like in glyphter

[image]

My stroke has become invisible where as no fill has become an actual fill... How can I possibly invert it in Illustrator to keep the original shape?

Comment: did you expanded your artwork? if not then try to expand your artwork by Object-Expand

Comment: I've realised this after hours of trying... Wish I saw this comment days ago.

Comment: yeah :D it could have saved your time a little XD anyway enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out a few days ago myself, you need to expand the object by selecting **Object > Expand**.

If the option is unavailable, you need to **Object > Expand Appearance** first and then **Object > Expand**.